# Google analytics: count users with different app configurations

Tags: google-analytics

I have an app I'd like to integrate Google analytics into. Specifically, I'm interested in finding what is the app's  configuration distribution between users. E.g. supposing that the app can be used in 3 different modes I would like to know the number of users for each mode providing that a user can change modes or even use more than one mode simultaneously. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you'd want to track that information using a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828). You can read about how to implement tracking of custom dimensions with analytics.js in the [Custom Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) guide.

Comment: So I need to define one custom dimension for this? What scope should I choose?

Comment: If the value associated with a particular user will never change, then you can set a scope of "user", though it honestly won't make that much of a difference since you're probably going to be sending that value with each hit anyway, in which case using a scope of "hit" would yield the same results in reports. The only reason to use "user" over "hit" is that if you set a value for that dimensions ever for a user, that's the value that gets used forever for that user, so arguably it could make the implementation easier.

Comment: In my case the user can change the app mode or work in more than 1 mode simultaneously. The mode is defined in a profile. There can be more than 1 profile per user. The app is already on the market, so I need to gather stats about existing users as well. How should I define the custom dimension for this and when should I send hits?

Comment: In that case use a scope of `hit`, set the value on the tracker as soon as the page loads (e.g. `ga('set', 'dimension1', APP_MODE)`, so then it gets sent with all subsequent hits.